# Network analysis using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, network-analysis

I have a water pipe network consisting of segments with attributes of pipe dimension, material of pipe and street location.

I need to create another network with different segments grouped by these attributes.
For example (going from the beginning of a line):

1. dimension - 0,4; material concrete; street 1
2. dimension - 0,3; material concrete; street 1
3. dimension - 0,3; material concrete; no street
4. dimension - 0,3; material concrete; street 2
5. dimension - 0,3; material plastic; street 2
6. dimension - 0,2; material plastic; street 2
7. dimension - 0,2; material plastic; street 3

How can I make it?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a table of edges linking related nodes in QGIS? It's not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, I am trying to create table with grouped segments according description above going from the beginning of line downstream.

Comment: That's what nodes and edges mean in network terminology.... segments is not a network term.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. Then yes, I am trying to create a table of edges linking related nodes.

Comment: Is GHydraulics (QGIS plugin) useful to you? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ghydraulic/